# How to fix increased height in NavigationView List row with Images in SwiftUI"

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I'm using Xcode 11 beta 5 and iPhone SE with iOS 13 beta 5.

In my app I have a NavigationView where each List row contains of two lines. I now want to add an Image(systemName: "circle") at the end of the text of the 2nd text line. When doing that, the space between the first and second text line increases.

I tried with adding using  `NSTextAttachment()` as described in the WWDC19 session on SF Symbols, but the image isn't shown at all. See Section 1 in the code and screenshot.

I also tried using using `Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "circle")!)`, the image is shown but the space between the lines increased. See Section 2.

Also, for reference, when just using text, the  line spacing as shown in Section 3 is what I want to have.

The code I used is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    func appendSymbol(string: String /*, image:UIImage*/ )-> String {
        let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
        let circleImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
        let redCircleImage = circleImage?.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        let circleAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: redCircleImage!)
        let circleString = NSAttributedString(attachment: circleAttachment)

        mutableString.insert(circleString, at: 3)
        return mutableString.string
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Text 1.1")
                            }
                            .border(Color.red)
                            HStack {
                                Text(appendSymbol(string: "Tex   t 1.2"))
                            }
                            .border(Color.green)
                        }
                        .border(Color.red)
                    }
                    .border(Color.red)
                }

                Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Text 2.1")
                            }
                            .border(Color.red)
                            HStack {
                                Text("Text 2.2")
                                Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "circle")!)
                            }
                            .border(Color.green)
                        }
                        .border(Color.red)
                    }
                    .border(Color.red)
                }

                Section(header: Text("Section 3")) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Text 3.1")
                            }
                            .border(Color.red)
                            HStack {
                                Text("Text 3.1")
                                Text("circle")
                            }
                            .border(Color.red)
                        }
                        .border(Color.red)
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot using the included code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9weTO.png)

Any idea why the first code (Section 1) isn't working, and how to fix the spacing?

Comment: Can someone reproduce this issue or knows how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try adding `spacing` after the `alignment` option of your `VStack`.

Example code for *Section 2* would be like this:

```swift
Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
    HStack {
        //adding the spacing option for the VStack
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Text("Text 2.1")
            }
            .border(Color.red)
            HStack {
                Text("Text 2.2")
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "circle")!)
            }
            .border(Color.green)
        }
        .border(Color.red)
    }
    .border(Color.red)
}
```

You could also use

```swift
Image(systemName: "circle")
```

instead of

```swift
Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "circle")!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, adding `spacing: 0` works fine!